# Dynamic HTMLControl's event not firing when session has expired

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 dynamic linkbuttons being created on my page based on a List stored in Session. After my page loaded, i waited till i know the session has expired and tried clicking the button then i noticed that the event did not fire and the buttons just disappeared. The buttons are working fine if the session has not expired yet.

Here's the button generation and regeneration:

```
void GetHelpdeskSystems()
{
    HelpdeskSysEOList hdList = new HelpdeskSysEOList();
    hdList.Load();
    List<HelpdeskSysEO> active = hdList.Where(h => h.IsActive).ToList();
    int x = 0;
    foreach (HelpdeskSysEO hd in active)
    {
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.ID = "lnkhd_" + x;
        lb.CommandArgument = hd.ID.ToString();
        lb.CommandName = "btnHelpdesk";
        lb.Attributes.Add("class", "lnkhelpdesk roundcor bluebtn");
        lb.Command += btnHeldesk_Command;
        HtmlGenericControl img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hd.ImageIcon))
            img.Attributes.Add("src", "images/icons/" + hd.ImageIcon);
        else
            img.Attributes.Add("src", "images/icons/default.png");
        HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span.InnerText = hd.HelpdeskName.Replace("Helpdesk", "").Replace("HELPDESK", "").Replace("helpdesk", "");
        lb.Controls.Add(img);
        lb.Controls.Add(span);
        divHelpdeskSystemsContent.Controls.Add(lb);
        x++;
    }
    Session[SESSION_KEY_HELPDESKLIST] = active;
}

void RegenerateHelpdeskSystems()
{
    List<HelpdeskSysEO> active = (List<HelpdeskSysEO>)Session[SESSION_KEY_HELPDESKLIST];
    int x = 0;
    foreach (HelpdeskSysEO hd in active)
    {
        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
        lb.ID = "lnkhd_" + x;
        lb.CommandArgument = hd.ID.ToString();
        lb.CommandName = "btnHelpdesk";
        lb.Attributes.Add("class", "lnkhelpdesk roundcor bluebtn");
        lb.Command += btnHeldesk_Command;
        HtmlGenericControl img = new HtmlGenericControl("img");
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hd.ImageIcon))
            img.Attributes.Add("src", "images/icons/" + hd.ImageIcon);
        else
            img.Attributes.Add("src", "images/icons/default.png");
        HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span.InnerText = hd.HelpdeskName.Replace("Helpdesk","").Replace("HELPDESK","").Replace("helpdesk","");
        lb.Controls.Add(img);
        lb.Controls.Add(span);
        divHelpdeskSystemsContent.Controls.Add(lb);
        x++;
    }
```

Here's the Command Event:

```
void btnHeldesk_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (Globals.GetCurrentUser() != null)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "btnHelpdesk")
        {
            HelpdeskSysEO hd = new HelpdeskSysEO();
            if (hd.load(int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())))
            {
                Globals.SetCurrentHelpdesk(hd);
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostback)
   {
       //Checking session here
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to share your code first if you want some help. :P

Comment: what happens after your session times out, do you still get this value Globals.GetCurrentUser()

Comment: No, I am getting those value from the Session. So Globals.GetCurrentUser() will return null if the Session has expired.